# [firebase_messaging]: The device has been locked and the silent push notification received at that time iOS app is getting crashed

Tags: android, ios, flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

In Android, it's working fine.

Steps to reproduce the issue in iOS,

(pre-condition)

The iOS app should be killed

1. Lock the device
2. Receive the VoIP incoming call

   At the time of ringing VoIP call we are getting a silent push notification from our server with the payload of contentAvailable: true

   File name: **FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.m** in *firebase_messaging* plugin

   As per the iOS guidelines flutter messaging package invoking the below method :

`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))completionHandler`

The app is terminated when the below **code** is executed.

[image]

Comment: TBH it's it's not clear what is state that is not working , but any way silent notification isn't grunted to deliver the notification to the app , specially for Voip calls

Comment: You should not send a silent notification for this case. You should send a voip push notification and use callkit to report an incoming call in your notification handler.

Comment: @mazenamr silent notification is delivered successfully.

Comment: @Paulw11 As per our requirement we need silent notification after ringing VOIP calls, we are not sending silent push notifications for VOIP calls, the VOIP call is working fine and ringing.

Comment: You need to get the exception/crash log as to why your app was terminated/crashed.

Comment: @Paulw11 Here are the last 3 lines of my app logs.

COMPLETED com.apple.pushLaunch.io.test.apptest:7EBC29 at priority 5 <private>!
default 15:46:14.192435+0530 dasd NO LONGER RUNNING com.apple.pushLaunch.io.test.apptest:7EBC29 ...Tasks running in group [com.apple.dasd.defaultNetwork] are 0!
default 15:46:14.192471+0530 dasd Removing a launch request for application <private> by activity <private>

Comment: @Paulw11 I've modified the issue in https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/12493. I hope you will get clear from that.

Comment: There should be a crash log with an exception message. iOS won't just kill your app silently but it won't log the exception to the device console either. Have you integrated something like crashlytics or have you tried a TestFlight build?  The chances are that that code isn't even necessary. I have personally aubmitted 2 PRs to flutterfire to fix bad objective C code.

Comment: @Paulw11 I've tried with TestFlight build also, but the same thing happened. Yes we've integrated Firebase crashlytics but not there any crash logs.

I am debugging with XCode and choosing the launch option using **wait for the executable to be launched**, then I am sending only a silent notification the logs are here:

Comment: [ERROR:flutter/shell/platform/darwin/graphics/FlutterDarwinContextMetalImpeller.mm(42)] Using the Impeller rendering backend.
Unable to read state restoration file. Probably the device is locked.
10.22.0 - [FirebaseCore][I-COR000005] No app has been configured yet.
[Firebase/Crashlytics] Version 10.22.0

Application could not restore state when launched in background while locked (4 seconds ago). Skipping snapshot/state save when asked to update snapshot in background, and terminating app.